# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException can't find a solution to my case

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, program-entry-point, nosuchelementexception

I have looked everyone where a reasonable explanation as to how I can fix the problem. Can someone look at my code and give me some suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoppingCartManager {

    public static void printMenu(ShoppingCart cart){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = " ";

      /*  String itemName = "none";
        String itemDescription = "none";
        int itemPrice = 0;
        int itemQuantity = 0;*/

        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("a - Add item to cart");
        System.out.println("d - Remove item from cart");
        System.out.println("c - Change item quantity");
        System.out.println("i - Output items' descriptions");
        System.out.println("o - Output shopping cart");
        System.out.println("q - Quit");

        //ItemToPurchase shopCart = new ItemToPurchase();

        input = read.next();
        read.close();



        switch (input){

            case "q" : System.out.println("Quit");
            break;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String customerName = "none";
        String todaysDate = "none";

        System.out.println("Enter the Customer's name: ");
        customerName = read.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Today's Date: ");
        todaysDate = read.nextLine();
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(customerName, todaysDate);


        System.out.println("Customer Name: " + cart.getCustomerName());
        System.out.println("Today's Date: " + cart.getDate());

        read.close();

        printMenu(cart);



        return;
    }
}
```

I get error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
at ShoppingCartManager.printMenu(ShoppingCartManager.java:24)
at ShoppingCartManager.main(ShoppingCartManager.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the call to `read.close()` in your `main` method.  Not only does this close the Scanner, it also closes the `System.in` stream.  Meaning that any time you need it (such as in your `printMenu` method), it is unavailable.

In your case, the `close()` call is simply unnecessary, and you can safely remove it.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. Now I'm trying to create a menu using switch statements and after an option is executed I am trying to get the menu to print again after the execution, so I have assigned the printMenu method into that option to see if it would execute the menu again and now it gives me the same exception error.

Comment: If this worked for you, please do not forget to upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: I did, but since I've only been a member since yesterday it wont reflect on the votes. Your help is very much appreciated.